# Prevent scrolling to selected row in datagridview when a new row is added

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I noticed that the Datagridview automatically scrolls to a row that the user selected when a record is added above the selected row.  When the record is added below the selected row it does not jump to the selected row.

I would like to prevent it from jumping to the selected row when the record is placed above it.  What can I do to get to behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also came across the same issue some time ago. I couldn't find a way to prevent that but set the focus to the previouly selected row by keeping that index in memory.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView.ClearSelection();